# Pass a function call to another without knowing the arguments

Tags: c, assembly, mingw

I'm trying to simply pass the control from a function to another. For example, every time a function `first` is called, I want to call the function `second` with the same arguments.

The catch is: I don't know how many arguments are being passed, their types, or the return type. Why? I'm trying to write a DLL wrapper using MingW on Windows. So, in this case, `first` is the symbol in the library, and `second` is my function. I know the DLL symbols, but not their prototypes.

I thought that writing `second` in C and the following code in assembly would suffice:

```
_first:
    jmp _second
```

or perhaps:

```
_first:
    call _second
    ret
```

but it just give me a segmentation fault when `first` is called.

Comment: gcc has a non-standard magic extension for forwarding. Look at builtin functions.

Comment: Thanks, can you be a little more specific? Look at builtin functions... where? In GCC source?

Comment: THey have a wonderful manual. [6.5 Constructing Function Calls](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html#Constructing-Calls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the @Deduplicator comment, this was the code that finally worked:

```
int first() 
{ 
    __builtin_return(
        __builtin_apply(
            (void(*)())second, __builtin_apply_args(), 512)); 
}
```

Why 512? I'm not sure. The manual says

> It is not always simple to compute the proper value for size. The value is used by __builtin_apply to compute the amount of data that should be pushed on the stack and copied from the incoming argument area.

If anyone has any idea on how to get a better estimate on the size, let me know and I edit the answer.

Comment: I think the `jmp _second;` implementation must work and and better than this magic value stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you are ideally looking for is a *naked* function, i.e., one for which the compiler does not add template code (to manipulate stack frames). Unfortunately, it appears as though there is no direct support for naked functions in GCC (there is in MSVC). The good news is that there appears to be a workaround, albeit slightly complicated, listed below.

http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=15

Something else you can do is explicitly preserve all register values. However, getting access to parameters becomes slightly more complicated, as you would have to first look at the disassembly, and then update `_second` accordingly to access any parameters.

```
_first:
    pushad
    call _second
    popad
    ret
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As for the link, I see the he encapsulates his assmebly call in a C function: I can't, because I don't know the parameters I'm receiving. I also tested your suggestion (pushad and popad), but I continue receiving a segmentation fault.